# How to convert this query to not equal to version

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

```
SELECT D.Name,D.Id
FROM category_devices AS CD JOIN
     Devices AS D
     ON CD.deviceId = D.Id
Where CD.DeviceId = D.Id AND D.AppId =2
```

Here is my Query i want to show all Devices which is CD.DeviceId != D.Id 
above query shows all devices which is equal how to convert this Query to not equal to ?

```
SELECT D.Name,D.Id
FROM category_devices AS CD JOIN
     Devices AS D
     ON CD.deviceId = D.Id
Where CD.DeviceId = D.Id AND D.AppId =2
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah if i will use not equal its gives null how to do except CD.DeviceId = D.Id these values means CD.DeviceId != D.Id how to write Right Syntax

Comment: I fail to understand the question. Can you provide example data? A few rows will go a long way.

Comment: @TheImpaler  JA-DT-FILL 5
YAS 6
MA-DT-FILL 7
JA-IN 8
MA-IN 9
DT31 10
DT22 11  ......>> This is result of query answer but i want all devices except those who are showed here

Comment: @TheImpaler simply i need to change this Query Where CD.DeviceId != D.Id this After Where so i can use Right Syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`:

```
SELECT D.Name, D.Id
FROM category_devices CD LEFT JOIN
     Devices D
     ON CD.deviceId = D.Id AND D.AppId = 2
WHERE D.Id IS NULL;
```

However, this will just return `NULL` values in the `SELECT` because there are no matches.  Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT CD.*
FROM category_devices CD LEFT JOIN
     Devices D
     ON CD.deviceId = D.Id AND D.AppId = 2
WHERE D.Id IS NULL;
```

Comment: but its giving null not any value ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want but if you want to know those in category_devices but not in devices and those in devices but not in category_devices -

```
drop table if exists category_devices,devices;

create table category_devices(deviceId int);
create table devices(id int,name varchar(2));
insert into category_devices values (1),(4);
insert into devices values (1,'aa'),(2,'bb'),(3,'cc');

select cd.deviceid,d.id,d.name
from category_devices cd
left join devices d on cd.deviceid = d.id
where d.id is null
union
select cd.deviceid,d.id,d.name
from devices d
left join category_devices cd on cd.deviceid = d.id
where cd.deviceid is null;

+----------+------+------+
| deviceid | id   | name |
+----------+------+------+
|        4 | NULL | NULL |
|     NULL |    2 | bb   |
|     NULL |    3 | cc   |
+----------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the NOT LIKE operator

```
SELECT D.Name,D.Id
FROM category_devices AS CD JOIN
 Devices AS D
 ON CD.deviceId = D.Id
Where CD.DeviceId NOT LIKE D.Id AND D.AppId =2
```

More info can be found here [SQL docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)